# DJI Developer, save video in my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, dji-sdk

I am approaching dji-sdk for iOS.
My goal is to integrate dji camera view into my app and start recording videos.
Is it possibile to save the video, getting an output filename, mostly like captureOutput does?

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) { 
...    
}
```

Thank you so much for the support!!!

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can, but it's not that easy.

The SDK doesn't provide a record to file function. So what you have to do it record the feed coming from the aircraft ([DJIVideoFeed](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/BaseClasses/DJIVideoFeeder_DJIVideoFeed.html)) and then re-feed it to the VideoPreviewer at the same bitrate.

It's a lot harder, but doable.